# How to specify custom call behaviour in classes?

Tags: javascript

Given an instance `v` of a class `Vector`, say `v = new Vector(3, 5, 7)`, is it somehow possible to use the syntax `v(k)` to call a specific method of the class `Vector` on `v` with argument(s) `k`?

To provide some context, I'd like to be able to use `v(k)` to call the method `getElem(k)` on `v`, which retrieves the `k`-th vector element of `v`. For example, `v(2)` would return `7`. In other words, `v(k)` would act as an alias or shorthand for `v.getElem(k)`.

Of course it would be possible to write a (custom) pre-processor to achieve the above, I just wondered whether there is a built-in way to realise it.

This question was inspired by the syntax of the C++ library `Eigen`, which allows one to [get/set matrix elements](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) in a similar way. It would be lovely to have something like this in JavaScript.

A bit of code to accompany the class mentioned above —

```
class Vector {
    constructor(...vecElems) {
        this.vecElems = vecElems;
    }

    getElem(k) {
        return this.vecElems[k];
    }

    dot(v) {
        return this.vecElems.reduce((aV, cV, cI) => aV + cV * v.vecElems[cI], 0);
    }
}

const v = new Vector(3, 5, 7);
const w = new Vector(4, 6, 8);
console.log(v.getElem(2), v.dot(w));
```

Comment: So you want `v(k)` to return `this.vecElements[k]`?

Comment: Fundamentally you need `v` to be a _function_ first and foremost, with properties and methods as required. I don't think you can do that with class syntax, though.

Comment: Well, that part is possible by putting `return (i) => this.vecElems[i];` into the constructor, but then you’d lose the other functionality. Why do you want _this_ syntax in particular? You’re just making it unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @0stone0 Indeed.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I'm used to similar syntax from working with `Eigen`, and became curious whether this would be possible in JS. If so, it would be easy to generalise this to a multi-dimensional setting, i.e. working with matrix/tensor classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally [was pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75327872/3310334) a fairly elegant injection-safe way to do it in ES6+ class syntax with a Proxy:

```js
class Vector extends Function {
    constructor(...vecElems) {
      super();
      this.vecElems = vecElems;
      return new Proxy(this, {
        apply(target, _, args) {
          return target.getElem(...args);
        }
      });
    }

  getElem(k) {
    return this.vecElems[k];
  }

  dot(v) {
    return this.vecElems.reduce((aV, cV, cI) => aV + cV * v.vecElems[cI], 0);
  }
}

const v = new Vector(3, 5, 7);
const w = new Vector(4, 6, 8);
console.log(v.getElem(2), v.dot(w));
console.log(v(2), v.dot(w));
```

This uses `Proxy`'s [`handler.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply) to wrap a callable object, which is in this case the class instance itself because it extends `Function`. It has to extend `Function` for the `x(...)` call syntax to be valid.

Comment: Great! Thanks for all the effort (including rephrasing the original question), much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the syntax `v[i]` return `v.getElem(i)` too, by subclassing `Array` itself:

```js
class Vector extends Array {
  constructor(...vecElems) {
    super(...vecElems);
  }

  getElem(k) {
    return this[k];
  }

  dot(v) {
    return this.reduce((aV, cV, cI) => aV + cV * v[cI], 0);
  }
}

const v = new Vector(3, 5, 7);
const w = new Vector(4, 6, 8);
console.log(v.getElem(0), v.getElem(1));
console.log(v[0], v[1]);
console.log(v.dot(w));
```

Comment: That's an interesting alternative I somehow didn't think about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems what you want is an object-generator (i.e. class) that returns functions that also have you custom properties.

Here's a way you can create such a "class":

```js
function Vector(...vecElems) {
  let members = {
    vecElems,
    getElem: function (k) {
      return this.vecElems[k];
    },
    dot: function (v) {
      return this.vecElems.reduce((aV, cV, cI) => aV + cV * v.vecElems[cI], 0);
    }
  };

  return Object.assign(members.getElem.bind(members), members);
}

const v = new Vector(3, 5, 7);
const w = new Vector(4, 6, 8);
console.log(v.getElem(0), v.getElem(1));
console.log(v.dot(w));
console.log(v(0), v(1));
```

This will be more performant than the ES6-class-syntax with `Proxy` approach, because member access via `Proxy` suffers its indirection.