# Extend Function in JavaScript with ES6+ class syntax

Tags: javascript, es6-class

My attempt:

```js
class SetOnceDict extends Function {
  constructor() {
    super('key', 'return this.get(key);')
  }
  items = {}
  add(key, value) {
    if (!this.items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.items[key] = value;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Duplicate key ${key}`);
    }
  }
  get(key) {
    return this.items[key];
  }
}

let dict = new SetOnceDict();
dict.add('one', 'foo');
dict.add('two', 'bar');

console.log(dict.items);
console.log(dict('one'));
```

I'd expect this to log

```
{ one: 'foo', two: 'bar' }
foo
```

instead it errors

```
return this.get(key);
            ^

TypeError: this.get is not a function
```

This works:

```js
console.log(dict.bind(dict)('one'));
```

But why would it have to be bound to *itself* when it should already have those properties?

Surprisingly (?) neither `super.bind(this);` nor `this.bind(this);`  in the constructor fix the problem.

How can I make an extension of function using ES6+ class syntax that has custom behaviour when called?

Comment: If you construct a function dynamically with `new Function()`, it doesn't get the current scope.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't think it should need the current scope for any reason in this case?

Comment: You need it for `this`.

Comment: @VLAZ what does the `this` in string function bodies refer to?

Comment: It's executed in global scope, so `window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Surprisingly (?) neither super.bind(this); nor this.bind(this); in the constructor fix the problem.

You can call `bind` in constructor. But it will create a new function so you need to:

1. Copy own properties, because it is a new object
2. Return the result.

```js
class SetOnceDict extends Function {
  constructor() {
    super('key', 'return this.get(key);')
    
    const out = this.bind(this) // create binded version
    
    Object.assign(out, this) // copy own properties
    
    return out // replace
  }
  items = {}
  add(key, value) {
    if (!this.items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.items[key] = value;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Duplicate key ${key}`);
    }
  }
  get(key) {
    return this.items[key];
  }
}

let dict = new SetOnceDict();
dict.add('one', 'foo');
dict.add('two', 'bar');

console.log(dict.items);
console.log(dict('one'));
```

Also you can use a `Proxy` :)

```js
class SetOnceDict extends Function {
  constructor() {
    super('key', 'return this.get(key);')
    
    return new Proxy(this, {
      apply(target, thisArg, args) {
        return target.call(target, ...args)
      }
    })
  }
  items = {}
  add(key, value) {
    if (!this.items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.items[key] = value;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Duplicate key ${key}`);
    }
  }
  get(key) {
    return this.items[key];
  }
}

let dict = new SetOnceDict();
dict.add('one', 'foo');
dict.add('two', 'bar');

console.log(dict.items);
console.log(dict('one'));
```

Comment: I had no idea about `Proxy`'s `handler.apply`. That's pretty cool, and looks like the best it's gonna get!

Comment: @minseong I wouldn't recommend either approach. Only for research purpose. :) Functions construction has perf penalties, Proxies have perf penalties as well.

Comment: In what way does Function construction have performance penalties? Only on construction of an instance of the class right? But the Proxy would impose performance penalties every time members are accessed?

Answer (score 0):

`this` does not actually refer to the function object itself within function bodies. To do that you need [arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee), although this is deprecated.

```js
class SetOnceDict extends Function {
  constructor() {
    super('key', 'return arguments.callee.get(key);')
  }
  items = {}
  add(key, value) {
    if (!this.items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.items[key] = value;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Duplicate key ${key}`);
    }
  }
  get(key) {
    return this.items[key];
  }
}

let dict = new SetOnceDict();
dict.add('one', 'foo');
dict.add('two', 'bar');

console.log(dict.items);
console.log(dict('one'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another ugly way that works using `Object.assign` and `bind`:

```js
class SetOnceDict extends Function {
  constructor() {
    super('key', 'return this.get(key);');
    return Object.assign(this.bind(this), this);
  }
  items = {}
  add(key, value) {
    if (!this.items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.items[key] = value;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Duplicate key ${key}`);
    }
  }
  get(key) {
    return this.items[key];
  }
}

let dict = new SetOnceDict();
dict.add('one', 'foo');
dict.add('two', 'bar');

console.log(dict.items);
console.log(dict('one'));
```

Comment: TBH, the class syntax is just a bad fit here. Native functions just aren't really fit to do what you want. It's fitting a square peg in a round hole. [Something like this](https://jsbin.com/foroden/1/edit?js,console) makes more sense to me.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the frame challenge and insight, and all of your comments on the question. I agree with you that that seems way more appropriate. I asked this question in the hope to learn more about JS and where my knowledge is missing the pieces to make it work (even if it's not desirable), and now because of your comments and the accepted answer I've been shown a lot. Thanks!